Could the Orion Project be revived on Mars?
Recently Elon Musk stated,

"I'd simply come to the conclusion that if something didn't happen to
improve rocket technology, we'd be stuck on Earth forever."

Could the Orion Project be revived on Mars?
How far the Partial Nuclear Test Ban Treaty which was one of the causes it was abandoned goes?
Does it mean you can't detonate nuclear bombs on Mars either? Or was it only applicable
to nuclear bombs detonated near Earth? Can't you detonate nuclear bombs on Mars on the name of one of the countries which didnt sign the treaty?

You first would have to lug all the stuff to Mars that is required to make nuclear bombs and  giant space ships. If you already know how to do that, then there is probably not a lot of incentive left to build an Orion type ship.

Mars? Only Earth is capable. Shipping it there makes it overall much harder, not easier. There would need to be clear goals that are well supported - launching FROM Earth won't be. With sustained "regular" type launch reliability (don't want loads of nuclear bombs blown apart on the pad), assembled in space for in-space use only, fired up well clear of Earth it hypothetically might win enough support to seek and negotiate treaty exemptions or changes. Those treaty exemptions are probably the most achievable bit.

I know a lot more about Project Orion than the nuclear test ban treaties, but I would generally think that you wouldn’t be allowed to do that.
There are bans on placing weapons of mass destruction (WMDs) in space. If you were to put a nuclear weapon in space and detonate it, it wouldn’t physically damage much nearby by shockwave (since, you know, no air in space), but the heat it generates would have to go somewhere, and the resulting electromagnetic pulse would carry a lot of heat to nearby objects (i.e. metal-melting) as well as probably destroy any electronics in line-of-sight (including communications and research satellites, and the ISS!).
Even if we were to lift that ban, NPP still suffers the issue that by design it requires holding a bunch of nukes on your ship at any given time (barring 3 Body Problem-esque staircase systems, which really aren’t that different anyway). This inevitably both violates that treaty and regardless puts a massive number of nuclear bombs floating through space at extremely high speed. If I disliked any particular country, I would go to the interplanetary gas station, buy some fuel, go to the hardware store, buy some spare heat shields, and do a do-it-yourself MIRV nuclear weapon, then drop it on Earth.
Doing it on Mars wouldn’t necessarily be better. Wherever we are, we’re building ultra-high-speed ships with tons of nuclear weapons on board, and that would pose many more dangers than benefits. I’m not sure about the particulars of the test ban treaties, but at least in spirit they extend everywhere in the Universe - the goal is to stop people from building nuclear weapons, not to stop them from building nukes on Earth.
Not to say that we’ll never colonize other planets/stars. We don’t necessarily need Orion in particular, just a very high specific impulse. Maybe plasma/electric propulsion will come through, or maybe we’ll figure out fusion and run hyper-efficient engines on the solar wind itself. Maybe one day we’ll figure out how to bend spacetime to our will and equip our first ship with a warp drive. But Orion has always been a little disconnected from reality in that its proponents thought/think that it’s okay to load up a Mach-30 vehicle with many tons of nuclear weapons and send it off to who-knows-where.

I believe the ban on nuclear weapons that got the Orion project cancelled is about not propagating radioactive material in the atmosphere, nothing to do with the risk of nuclear weapons being used for non pacific purposes. I see no reason why that would be a problem on Mars for inhabitants of Earth. Also, there are nuclear weapons which have half the yield of non nuclear weapons, so it's not like you have to build the super destructive weapons

This could possibly be resolved by defining the nuclear weapon more precisely. Nuclear propulsion of civilian spacecraft is not a mass destruction weapon  by itself.
